# Set value to GWT checkbox

Tags: html, gwt, user-interface, checkbox

I want to set value (number or string) to checkbox. This code

```
final CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox("Some label");
checkBox.getElement().setAttribute("value", i.toString());
checkBox.getElement().getStyle().setProperty("color", colorList.get(i));
checkBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            Object sender = event.getSource();
            if (sender == checkBox) {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)event.getSource();
                Window.alert(checkBox.getFormValue());
            }
        }
});
```

creates  the following HTML:

```
<td align="left" style="vertical-align: top;">
<span class="gwt-CheckBox" value="3" style="color: rgb(128, 105, 155);">
<input id="gwt-uid-4" type="checkbox" value="on" tabindex="0">
<label for="gwt-uid-4">Some label</label>
</span>
</td>
```

The attribute `value` is set to `span` instead of `input`. The `Window.alert(checkBox.getFormValue())` shows message with string 'on', instead of '3'.

Comment: What do you mean by setting a value (other than on/off) to a checkbox? Do you want a label next to the checkbox?

Comment: User can see checkbox with label 'Some label'. But when the checkbox is checked and the form is submitted, some other value is sent which represents the checkbox e.g. '3', but no 'Some label'.

Comment: Are you using a FormPanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value for `checkBox` to `"someValue"` using [`setFormValue`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/CheckBox.html#setFormValue%28java.lang.String%29)

```
  checkBox.setFormValue("someValue");
```

Comment: :). I think there is no changes in Check box doc.Anyways thanks for the correction and update.

Answer (score 3):

The property "value= on / off" has some predefined meaning for the check box. So don't use the property "value" to store numbers.

If you really want to store the numbers use your own custom properties like -

```
checkBox.getElement().getFirstChildElement().setAttribute( "customProperty", "3" );
```

and to access the property use -

```
checkBox.getElement().getFirstChildElement().getAttribute( "customProperty" );
```